# nginx spdy support not working

Tags: nginx, spdy

i try to install nginx with spdy support following here:[ningx spedy](http://nginx.org/patches/spdy/README.txt), i used this configuration command

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-openssl="/..../openssl/openssl-1.0.1c"
```

but when i go and check my site on spdycheck.org, i got the result that NPN is enabled but spdy is not, can't find any info where i can start cracking now(nothing in  the error log), any ideas folks?

Edit:

```
# Force URL on https and www
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://www. example.com$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    ssl_certificate    /usr/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /usr/ssl/nginx/server.key;
    server_name  www. example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.tedxnanjing.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.tedxnanjing.error error;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    location / {
       root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }


    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf|log|zip|tar)$ {
       root /var/www/html;
       expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable SPDY in the `listen` directive? Please provide the relevant parts of your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What version of NGINX are you running on? Type: `nginx -V` or `nginx -v` for output without additional arguments. If you run NGINX lower than 1.5.10, you are running SPDY draft 2, which is deprecated as far as I know and not showing up properly in browsers. Also you need OpenSSL version 1.0.1 and above, preferably version 1.0.1g, which includes a patch for the Heartbleed bug.

How do you check if SPDY is working? My recommendation is to check via `chrome://net-internals/#spdy` in Google Chrome (just type it in your Chrome search field) or via Firefox SPDY Indicator add-on.